# Can I use VECM, GARCH and HAR-RV for forecasting of carbon price?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, garch, vector-error-correction-model

Can I use VECM, GARCH and HAR-RV for forecasting of carbon price?
I'm not sure the assumptions of the models don't contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly try to use these models or their pairwise combinations. The only pairwise combination that would not make sense is GARCH + HAR-RV, as both model the conditional variance. Having two models for the same underlying quantity would indeed be contradictory. On the other hand, VECM + constant* variance, VECM + GARCH, VECM + HAR-RV, constant* mean + GARCH and constant* mean + HAR-RV would not be contradictory.

Once you formulate and estimate one or more of these models, you may benefit from assessing their statistical adequacy and their forecasting performance. They may turn out to be poor models of the underlying time series; there is no *ex ante* guarantee they would be good.

*It could be constant or some other model.